# Fill empty vertical space in a cell

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to fill the space left in a cell originated by another cell with more height in the same row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endhead

8.7 This is some contractual boring text that people read literally &
8.7 This is a modification of the boring text that people also read literally. This is new text without usefull information. \\
8.8 This is some contractual boring very very very very very very very very very very very very long text that people read literally &
8.8 This is a modification of the very long text. \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Like colour, or fill with dots or lines the space between "..literally" and "8.8 This.." in column 1, and "..long text." and the end of the table in column 2.

I tried using `\rule`, `\vspace`, `\vfill`, and `\hrulefill`, and I just get the first line filled... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A manual solution, but, can help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endhead

8.7 This is some contractual boring text that people read literally \dotfill\par\dotfill\par\dotfill\par &
8.7 This is a modification of the boring text that people also read literally. This is new text without usefull information. \\
8.8 This is some contractual boring very very very very very very very very very very very very long text that people read literally &
8.8 This is a modification of the very long text. \dotfill\par\dotfill\par\dotfill\par\dotfill\par\dotfill\par\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This was done by adding multiple `\dotfill\par`s untill the two cells are the same height. You can drop the last `par` if you don't need the extra space at the bottom of the cell. Sure, this is not an automatic solution, but it requires little effort when the cell content changes.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option using some marks placed with the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library to draw filled rectangles (two or three runs are needed for the elements to reach their final positions):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{0.3\linewidth}|p{0.3\linewidth}|}
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline \textbf{Original Contract} & \textbf{Modification} \\
\hline
\endhead

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[gray!30]
  ([yshift=-3pt]{{pic cs:enda}|-{pic cs:starta}}) 
    rectangle 
  ([yshift=10pt]{{pic cs:middlea}|-{pic cs:enda}});
\fill[gray!30]
  ([yshift=-3pt]{pic cs:middleb}) 
    rectangle 
  ({{pic cs:endb}|-{pic cs:startb}});
\end{tikzpicture}

8.7 This is some contractual boring text that people read literally\tikzmark{starta}\hfill\tikzmark{middlea} &
8.7 This is a modification of the boring text that people also read literally. This is new text without usefull information. \\
\tikzmark{enda}8.8 This is some contractual boring very very very very very very very very very very very very long text that people read literally\tikzmark{startb} &
8.8 This is a modification of the very long \tikzmark{endb}text.\hfill\tikzmark{middleb} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ,@GonzaloMedina Your code is not automatic. It can break, for example, if we make cell 1 read: `8.7 This is some contractual boring text that people read literally very very very very very very long text that people read literally very very very very very very long text that people read literally`

Comment: @AboAmmar I didn't claim it to be automatic; using `\tikzmark` is hardly ever automatic since marks have to be placed.

Comment: @AboAmmar By the way, why did you delete your answer? (And why it was downvoted, I wonder).

Comment: ,@GonzaloMedina Since I like _TikZ_ in general, at a first sight I thought your solution can be made automatic, but I know, this is hard to implement. (+1) BTW.

Comment: @AboAmmar Yes, I have some ideas to make it automatic, but no time to think about them or to code them. Thanks for your vote. I also up-voted your answer, but still wondering why the down-vote specially with no comment.